# start a program if a statement is met

Tags: vbscript

i want to make an authority level system on my pc so i want a vbs program that check if a file exists and if so starts a program but it says error line 5 char 1 object required " but when i do it it says expected statement

```
Option Explicit
DIM fso  
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
If fso.FileExists("C:\code\login\authlevel\2.txt") or 
fso.FileExists("C:\code\login\authlevel\3.txt") or 
fso.FileExists("C:\code\login\authlevel\4.txt") Then
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
 WScript.Quit()
Else
  WScript.Echo("incorrect autority")
End If

WScript.Quit()
```

any help would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are not setting `fso` to be anything, but you're trying to use it as a file system object, you need to `set` that reference as I've done below.

You also appear to have split the code across multiple lines at the `OR` statements.  If you want to do that (usually for readability purposes) you need to tell `vbscript` the next line is a continuation of the code and not a new line of code like this, using an underscore character:

```
Option Explicit
DIM fso  
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
If fso.FileExists("C:\code\login\authlevel\2.txt") or _ 
fso.FileExists("C:\code\login\authlevel\3.txt") or _ 
fso.FileExists("C:\code\login\authlevel\4.txt") Then
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
 WScript.Quit()
Else
  WScript.Echo("incorrect authority")
End If

WScript.Quit()
```